# How to access contacts data through content provider

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-intent, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I want to display contacts in carousel format. I have written an application for creating 3D carousel view using open gl es library. Now I want to display contacts using that application. How can I load the data of contacts into my application?

Answer (score 0):

```
intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, PICK_CONTACT);


 public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

            switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        // other data is available for the Contact. I have decided
                        // to only get the name of the Contact.
                        String name = c
                                .getString(c
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    }
                }
```

and see this link also

http://eclipsed4utoo.com/blog/android-open-contacts-activity-return-chosen-contact/